# Why solr reindex data on highlighting?

Tags: java, solr, tokenize

I wrote custom tokenizer for solr, when I first add records to solr, they are going throug my tokenizer and other filters, when they are going through my tokenizer I call web service and add needed attributes. After it I can use search without sending requests to web service. When I use search with highlighting data are going through my tokenizer again, what should I do for not going through tokenizer again?

Answer (score 0):

When the highlighter is run on the text to highlight, the analyzer and tokenizer for the field is re-run on the text to score the different tokens against the submitted text, to determine which fragment is the best match for the query produced. You can see [this code around line #62 of Highlighter.java in Lucene](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-highlighter/4.9.0/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.java?av=f#61).

There are however a few options that might help for negating the need to re-parse the document text, all given as options on [the community wiki for Highlighting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting):

For the standard highlighter:

> It does not require any special datastructures such as termVectors,
> although it will use them if they are present. If they are not, this
> highlighter will re-analyze the document on-the-fly to highlight it.
> This highlighter is a good choice for a wide variety of search
> use-cases.

There are also two other Highlighter-implementations you might want to look at, as either one uses other support structures that might avoid doing the retokenizing / analysis of the field (I think testing it will be a lot quicker for you than for me right now).

> **FastVector Highlighter**: The FastVector Highlighter requires term vector options (termVectors, termPositions, and termOffsets) on the field.
>
> **Postings Highlighter**: The Postings Highlighter requires storeOffsetsWithPositions to be configured on the field. This is a much more compact and efficient structure than term vectors, but is not appropriate for huge numbers of query terms.

You can switch the highlighting implementation by using `hl.useFastVectorHighligter=true` or adding `<highlighting class="org.apache.solr.highlight.PostingsSolrHighlighter"/>` to your searchComponent definition.

Comment: I think I should use it, but I haven't got any search component definition and if define it search isn't working.